# How to manage memory when using ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a large mount of tasks need to execute with `multithreading`.

I use the `ExecutorService` to submit lots of `Callable objects`, and each `Callable object` contains some `resource` which is needed for executing.

**Problem**

These tasks are so many that the `Callable objects` submitted to `ExecutorService` occupy too much memory then the `heap` is exhausted.

I want to know, when does the `JVM` release the space for these `Callable objects`?

Does it do this immediately after the task is done and how could I to manage the memory used for `ExecutorService`?

I want to control the submission to `ExecutorService`, for example, when the memory is not enough then block the submission util some tasks completed and free space. Could it?

---

The whole code is too compliticated, I will attach the main frame of my code.

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Result> {

  ... // Some members

  public MyCallable(...) {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public Result call() throws Exception {
    ... // Doing the task
  }
}

class MyFutureTask extends FutureTask<Result> {

  ... // Some members

  public MyFutureTask(...) {
    super(new MyCallable(...));
  }

  @Override
  public void done() {
    Result result = get();
    ... // Something to do immediately after the task is done
  }
}

// Here is the code to add tasks
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
while (...) {
  ... // Reading some data from files
  executor.submit(new MatchFutureTask(...));
}
executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: An answer to your problem can be given if you add a code snippet. What kind of executor service are you using? What does many mean (i.e. how many is many)?

Comment: PS: I have a feeling that you are actually facing a memory leak problem (I guess in some other part of your app you are holding references to your Callables) and not an executor service problem.

Comment: @AlexCalugarescu I use Executors.newFixedThreadPool() to create ExecuteService, so it should be ThreadPoolExecutor. And the "many" means, the original text file is more than 3GB, I read it and covert to some objects to store in Callables, so I think it's really too many.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using the ExecutorService, you must be passing a BlockingQueue into the constructor, right?  I am assuming you are using a ThreadPoolExecutor.  Use an ArrayBlockingQueue with a fixed capacity, and pass ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy to the ThreadPoolExecutor constructor.  This will fairly effectively limit your submission rate if you set the maximumPoolSize to some reasonable value.

To answer your first question, the VM will release the memory "at some time after" there are no longer any references to objects.  If the Callable is self-contained in terms of state, once it is finished executing, the VM should garbage collect it before giving you an out of memory error.

Comment: Well, I just use Executors.newFixedThreadPool() to create ExecuteService, so I didn't pass a BlockingQueue. What does the BlockingQueue do?

Comment: A BlockingQueue will only allow a specific number of tasks to be queued in the executor.  Executors.newFixedThreadPool() will allow an unlimited number of tasks.

Comment: I think I solve it. I change to create the ThreadPoolExecutor object by myself, which could really control the size of the waiting task queue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

The method `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` will tell you how much free memory the JVM has.  You could write a `ThreadFactory` implementation that checks this value before creating a new thread.

Answer (score 4):

Seemed that using Executors.newCachedThreadPool() reduced memory by 30% - 60%